# nginx reverse proxy to apache mod_wsgi doesn't work

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to run a django site with apache mod-wsgi with nginx as the front-end to reverse proxy into apache.

In my Apache ports.conf file:

```
NameVirtualHost 192.168.0.1:7000
    Listen 192.168.0.1:7000

    <VirtualHost 192.168.0.1:7000>
    DocumentRoot /var/apps/example/
    ServerName example.com

    WSGIDaemonProcess example
    WSGIProcessGroup example

    Alias /m/ /var/apps/example/forum/skins/
    Alias /upfiles/ /var/apps/example/forum/upfiles/
    <Directory /var/apps/example/forum/skins>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/apps/example/django.wsgi

    </VirtualHost>
```

In my nginx config:

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  example.com;

        location / {            
            include /usr/local/nginx/conf/proxy.conf;
            proxy_pass http://192.168.0.1:7000;
            proxy_redirect default;
            root /var/apps/example/forum/skins/;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

    }
```

After restarting both apache and nginx, nothing works, example.com simply hangs or serves index.html in my /var/www/ folder.

I'd appreciate any advice to point me in the right direction.  I've tried several tutorials online to no avail.

Comment: Have you confirmed whether Apache/mod_wsgi works by access the backend web server first, ie., bypassing nginx?

Comment: Hmm, good point.  It worked before when I had PHP, but then I installed mod_wsgi and everything seems broken.

Comment: ok nevermind it works now, the problem was /root/.python-eggs. It was trying to find python eggs at /var/www/...

Comment: You might post that as the answer so that this question gets marked as answered.

Answer (score 1):

I've got a sneaky suspicion that the problem might be `/root/.python-eggs` -- I think you might be trying to find python eggs at `/var/www/...` ;)